# Setup Amazon S3 backup on QNAP using s3cmd

Tags: amazon-s3, backup, cron, s3cmd, qnap

I own a QNAP-219P and I want to set this up manually using s3cmd.

I did quite a bit of research on this, and here are the references I got:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20091120211330/http://codemonkeybrown.com/qnaps3.html
- http://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Running_Your_Own_Application_at_Startup
- http://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Add_items_to_crontab
- http://blog.wingateuk.com/2013/03/cloud-backup-on-qnap-nas.html?showComment=1413660445187#c8935766892046800936

I'm trying to get the s3cmd to work on my TS-219P.

I got everything to work (on command line), even running the script file (s3-backup.sh) on command line:

```
#!/bin/bash   <-- I also tried #!/bin/sh

/share/maintenance/s3cmd-1.5.0-rc1/s3cmd --rr sync -rv /share/all-shared-folders/emilie/ s3://kingjim-backup/kingjim-nas/emilie/ >> /share/maintenance/log/s3cmd/backup_`date "+%Y%m%d-%H-%M"`.log    <-- I also tried running s3cmd via python by adding /usr/bin/python on the front.
```

If I run using the SSH command prompt, it seems to work perfectly.

The problem though, is the cronjob. I can confirm the cronjob trigger, and it was run, because my log file (the one above) was generated, but the log is always empty, even though I'm sure there are some new files created/modified.

This is my cronjob task:

```
14 3 * * * /share/maintenance/s3-backup.sh 2>&1 | logger
```

I've done a number of different variations on the above, but couldn't find out what was missing.

I feel like some dependency is missing when the crontab is running, as compared to when I run it on command prompt.  But I don't know how to debug crontab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the problem was that the s3cmd configuration file was not found when running s3cmd.

So the fix was simply to copy this .s3config file to a safe shared folder, and then call the s3cmd with the "--config" parameter followed by the file.

Like this:

```
/share/maintenance/s3-backup/s3cmd/s3cmd --config
/share/maintenance/s3-backup/s3cmd.config --rr sync -rv /share/MD0_DATA/ s3://xxx-backup/xxx-nas/ >> /share/maintenance/s3-backup/logs/backup_`date "+%Y%m%d-%H-%M"`.log 2>&1
```